# Playing AUDIO from WebView

Tags: android, webview, audio-player

I've been looking for how to play audio from any website inside the webview?

I've noticed Chrome Browser playing the audio but My WebView app doesn't play.
Can you please provide me any resource or code snippet?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, hope it solves your problem.

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Also, add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` into `activity tag` in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through Javascript Interface

Create a Class WebInterface

```
public class WebInterface{
    Context mContext;

    WebInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void playSound(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void pauseSound(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
In your WebView class

WebView browser;
browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);   
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.addJavascriptInterface(new WebInterface(this), "Android");        
browser.loadUrl("http://someurl.com");
In HTML code

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function playSound(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }

    function pauseSound(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="playSound('Sound Played!')" />
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="pauseSound('Sound Paused!')" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer but please tell me how i add the following HTML code and where it should be added? your help be highly recommended!

Comment: you're welcome!! very used to these questions by now, hence the speedy answer. to be honest, not too familiar with the placement as it was a challenge in one of my classes to write the code but i do find that webtoolkitonline has a great interface and its really good to write code in so give that a go! sorry if i wasnt much help past this. good luck walid  !

Comment: You exported Android.playSound() and .pauseSound() but you are calling Android.showToast() instead.  Isn't that an error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with WebView on Android where audio stopped working when we switched WebView to use HTTPS. **Looks like audio doesn't work with HTTPS.**

**Solution** was not to load audio file, it was to include audio file in javascript:

```
var base64Audio = "data:audio/mpeg;base64,//uQxAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
var dummyAudio = new Audio(base64Audio);
dummyAudio.load();
dummyAudio.play();
```

Audio as base64 template:

```
data:audio/mpeg;base64,[MP3_AS_BASE64]
```

You can use any online encoder to encode audio file to base64.